# Given $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^a(1-x)^bdx$, find truth/falsity

Tags: integration

> Given $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^a(1-x)^bdx$, where $a,b$ are integers, with $a \geq 1$, $b \geq 1$. Is the following true: $I(2,2)=2I(1,1)$?

I understood this to be whether this integral is linear, like $I(c(a,b))=c(I(a,b))$, where $c\in \mathbb{R}$. I declare this to be false. If you substitute $a=1, b=1$, then the integral evaluates to $2\int_{0}^{1}0dx$, which is clearly not the case with $a=2, b=2$.

Next, is $I(a,b)=I(b,a)$? This is of course a property of symmetry, if there ever was one. This time there's no way to verify whether it holds. Shall I try a few examples to see if it disproves it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I(a,b)$ be given by the integral

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^b\,dx$$

for $a>-1$ and $b>-1$.  Enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$, we find that

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^1 (1-x)^a x^b\,dx=I(b,a)$$

as was to be shown!

---

Now let's look at $I(2,2)$.  Then, we have

$$I(2,2)=\int_0^1 x^2(1-x)^2\,dx=\frac1{30}$$

However,

$$I(1,1)=\int_0^1 x(1-x)\,dx=\frac16$$

So, $I(2,2)=\frac15 I(1,1)$

Comment: this was an excellent answer. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @Mark Viola Me, once again ! To this elementary question, I just gave an answer using a general result that can be useful to know (and that can be extended to real values of $a$ and $b$ through $\Gamma$ function).

Comment: @JeanMarie I've upvoted your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your integral is a version of the so-called ["Beta" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), with a simple closed form expression for positive integer exponents:

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^1 x^{a} (1-x)^b dx= \dfrac{a! b!}{(a+b+1)!}\tag{1}$$

This gives an answer to your second question: yes, $I(a,b)=I(b,a).$

For the first one, one obtains from (1):

$$I(2,2)=\dfrac{2 \times 2}{120}=\dfrac{1}{30} \ \ \text{and} \ \ I(1,1)=\dfrac{1 \times 1}{6}=\dfrac{1}{6}$$

Thus the exact answer to your first question is: no, we have

$$I(2,2)=\dfrac15 I(1,1).$$

Comment: (+1) for your complementary solution